# Upcoming event oddity

Tags: discussion

This question: [In response to the OpenSSL Poodle vulnerability should I disable SSLv3?](https://serverfault.com/questions/637605/in-response-to-the-openssl-poodle-vulnerability-should-i-disable-sslv3) appears as an "Upcoming event". Why? The number of DVs doesn't warrant it in the least.

Comment: More amusingly, it's an upcoming event on October 15th - a couple days in the past.

Comment: WE'VE BEEN POODLED!

Comment: Most of the downvotes are unwarranted, in my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Most of the downvotes probably came for the original question which is ... lacking and easily tested so yeah no research, no effort.

Comment: Most of the downvotes came after. It was at +2/-2 when I did the edit. I suspect some of the downvotes are from the Question being posted in The Comms Room.

Answer (score 2):

I think @DeerHunter's suggestion is a better way to go:

1. Make a meta post about the issue in question, linking to the main post (or posts) you want to highlight.  (Such a post is totally appropriate for meta, it would be a post about a post.)
2. Mark the meta post with a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag
3. Profit!

In response to @Chris' "really?" comment, yes, this would really be a better way to go, it's way less confusing than calling it an event and showing a wildly incorrect date.

If you do this again, I'm certain you'll get more WTF? comments and I'm almost certain you'll get another meta question asking what it means.  Rather than try to bend the Event feature out of shape, use a mechanism that already exists.

Comment: I still disagree that labeling it a "Hot Meta Topic" is any less confusing. Also, how "wildly incorrect" is the date the bug was publish? I curious to know what date *you* think would have been *wildly correct*.

Comment: @ChrisS Now I've gotta ask "really?"  You think an upcoming event that shows up with a date of 2 days ago isn't confusing?  That's what I meant by "wildly incorrect:" an upcoming event in the past.

Comment: I never claimed it wasn't confusing, thanks for the strawman. But your proposal seems no less confusing, yet you present it as though it's obviously superior. I think you guys would have whinged no matter what I had done - I'm so tired of the whining when anything changes...

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered suggesting something if I didn't think it was better.  I didn't realize that saying "this thing is confusing, I think this other thing is better," was whining.

Comment: You seem unusually grumpy @ChrisS :(